# Handling categories and sub categories MySQL or JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, foreach

I am trying to find the best way to handle category and sub category. I have 20 category and 50 sub category. Which of these is best way to do so :

1. Save data in a json file and reading content directly on client side.
2. Save data in database in single table and using parent id to see the relation and using foreach on result array inside another foreach of same array.
3. Save data in database in two table, making one sql call to parent category another one call to sub category and using parent id to see the relation and using foreach of sub category array inside another foreach of parent array.
4. Save data in database in two table, making one sql call to parent category and then inside its foreach making multiple sql calls to database.

I tried to find the best practice to handle categories but couldn't find any article for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends purely on how complex your database schema and other entities relate to the categories. And how you intend to read the information.

The json approach would be faster, but has issues when it comes to queries that would require you to link up to category additional information.

Another approach I have used and had good performance is storing all categories in a single table. The relationships are not stored in the main table.

Another table stores the relationships as graph edges. This is quite advantageous if you have cyclic relationships within the categories. Or more than one parent.

The schema would look like :

categories ( id, name )
category_edges ( parent_id, child_id)

I used [oqgraph](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/oqgraph-examples/) with my implementation to get the relationships queries faster. But that was with MariaDB and not mysql.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I guess you are saying the 3rd approach is best out of these 4, to create two tables and then make array in php based on the relation between them.

Comment: not necessarily. It's difficult for me to suggest a solution without having a clear idea about the impact on the rest of the application. But in general practice yeah , it makes sense for the cats to be on a table. But the solution I have suggested is different from the 3rd Option. It implements the category structure as a graph.